# Adding an additional column with rank ordering in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, ranking, information-retrieval

I have the following code:

```
ID= # type is <class 'str'>
dictionary={} #Dictionary

 with open('result.PRED', 'a') as fileOut:
        for item in dictionary.keys():
            print(Question_ID,item,dictionary[item],sep='\t',file=fileOut)
```

which generates the following results from my document ranking model:

```
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C1    0.0
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C10   0.0
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C2    0.0
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C3    0.196116135138
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C4    0.353553390593
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C5    0.205267008777
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C6    0.408248290464
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C7    0.0
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C8    0.0
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C9    0.0
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C1    0.301637573861
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C10   0.199260956948
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C2    0.147292928305
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C3    0.0860264946736
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C4    0.0819313340205
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C5    0.244377512197
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C6    0.161126919432
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C7    0.152303771019
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C8    0.0
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C9    0.0
```

I need to create an additional column which is a rank based on the score given in column 3. Also, the second column is not properly sorted, as C10 appears before C2.

For example, I am trying to get as follows;

```
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C1    0.0    4
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C2    0.0    5
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C3    0.196116135138    3
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C4    0.353553390593    1
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C5    0.205267008777    2
.....    .....    ....  ....
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C10   0.0    6
```

I have been trying for a long time with various ways, and I could not find a way to handle this.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use your output string as input data, use `split()` method to get the list and sort it by third item, and then sort the list once again by multiple keys , here is the code:

```
r="""Q1_R1 Q1_R1_C1 0.0
Q1_R1 Q1_R1_C10 0.0
...
Q1_R6 Q1_R6_C6 0.161126919432
Q1_R6 Q1_R6_C7 0.152303771019
Q1_R6 Q1_R6_C8 0.0
Q1_R6 Q1_R6_C9 0.0"""

l=[i.split(' ') for i in r.split('\n')]
tmp=sorted(l,key=lambda x:float(x[2]),reverse=True)

for i in sorted([j+[i+1] for i,j in enumerate(tmp)],key=lambda x:(x[0],int(x[1].split('C')[-1]))):
    print("\t".join(map(str,i)))
```

Result:

```
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C1    0.0 13
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C2    0.0 15
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C3    0.196116135138  7
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C4    0.353553390593  2
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C5    0.205267008777  5
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C6    0.408248290464  1
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C7    0.0 16
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C8    0.0 17
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C9    0.0 18
Q1_R1   Q1_R1_C10   0.0 14
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C1    0.301637573861  3
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C2    0.147292928305  10
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C3    0.0860264946736 11
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C4    0.0819313340205 12
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C5    0.244377512197  4
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C6    0.161126919432  8
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C7    0.152303771019  9
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C8    0.0 19
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C9    0.0 20
Q1_R6   Q1_R6_C10   0.199260956948  6
```